# delay and fade in smoothly reset form function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I just discovered the reset function for all the fields in my contact form. I would like that this function is applied after some seconds and with a smooth fade in.

This is the code I have for the reset so the user can send again an email:

```
$( 'form' ).each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

I thought maybe something like this was possible? Maybe I need to add also a fadeOut function of the actual content inserted? But I'm not jQuery expert at this moment:

```
var formReset = $( 'form' ).each(function(){this.reset();});

formReset().delay('2000').fadeIn('500');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the reset in the callback from fadeIn / fadeOut.

Following snippet will fade out all inputs with type text and textareas. After this the value is cleaned and the elements are faded in:

```
function reset(){
    $('#myFormular').children('input:text, textarea').each(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
}


$('#resetButton').click(reset);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WsDe2/2/

Another solution is to animate the font color to the background color of the input element. Then clear the value and after this change to the native color:

```
function reset(){
    $('#myFormular').children('input:text, textarea').each(function(){
        var baseColor = $(this).css('color');

        $(this).animate({color : $(this).css('background-color')}, function(){
            $(this).val('');
            $(this).css('color', baseColor);
        });
    });
}


$('#resetButton').click(reset);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/WsDe2/4/

Comment: Mohler What do you mean with this?

Comment: Sorry, my answer could be a bit larger. If I understood you right, than you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/WsDe2/2/ You only have the opportunity to fade out the input elements and in the callback (function part after fading is finished) you have to change the val to '' and re-fade-in. Another way would be to animate the css color of those inputs, but jquery will need a plugin for this.

Comment: Here is another example based on dynamic color change: http://jsfiddle.net/WsDe2/3/. Note, that you need the plugin from http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/.

Answer (score 1):

```
   this.reset();
   setTimeout(function(){                          
         $('#correct').fadeOut(500);
   },2000);
```

Use `setTimeout`

Comment: Just tried what you said but the reset is still immediate. I tried the following: $('#correct').fadeIn(500);
                    $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled').attr('value', 'enviar');
                    $( 'form' ).each(function(){
                        this.reset();
                        setTimeout(function(){
                           this.fadeIn(500);
                           $('#correct').fadeOut(500);
                        },2000);
                    });

Comment: I inserted this on a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/PkSec/ But I do not know how to insert the php which does the final touch. Could you help me aroudn how to do this?

Comment: In the jsfiddle so you can see the end result of the javascript form. At least in this fiddle you can check the javascript I have at this moment... At this moment if I press submit it resets the form instantly and the correct div does not dissapear with a fade out either. This is of course not the intention..

Comment: I tried with your changes and what happens is that the correct div appears confirming its ok, the reset happens immediately and after some seconds nothing else happens. So the #correct div also does not dissapear... strange!

Comment: I cant check here on submit it gives me some error in json format

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41116/discussion-between-daniel-ramirez-escudero-and-vicky-gonsalves)